# Error while connecting source code management in Jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins

My Jenkins is installed on a remote server and I can access it through a particular URL. When I try to add source code management as git and provide the URL of my git repo, it gives me an error:

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h git@github.com:XXX.git HEAD" returned status code 128: stdout: stderr: Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exist

I can clone my git repo to my local.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! How have you set up authentication to your git repository? Could you please check that correct keys are used?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen How should i do it as soon as i enter the git repo url in the siurce cod emanagement it gives error. In credential i used my github email and password.
I am not sure how can i use my ssh key of remote Jenkins which i dont know to use in the credentials